# how to create a patch using the repo command?

Tags: git, repository

I'm currently working in the [CyanogenMod 9 source](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android), and I'd like to create a patch of all my changes. How can I use [`repo`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) to generate a patch that I can forward to a colleague for him to apply to his repository? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have zero experience with `repo`, but it looks like `repo diff` is your friend. That generates a standard diff (using `git diff`) which can be applied using either `git apply` (if you're willing to use git directly), or using the venerable `patch` utility (invoked as `patch -p1`).

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks!